# Disable HEX Code Converting Forward Slash (/) to &#x2F; using Node JS, Mongoose, and Express in AdminLTE

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose, adminlte

I am trying to store data in Atlas, when i write "/", it got converted to / in my code I have declare all the variable as string:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

mongoose.pluralize(null);

var presenceSchema = new Schema({

  propic_path: String,

  nama: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },  //name
  tanggal: { type: String, required: true },             //date
  waktu: { type: String, required: true },               //time
  activity: { type: String, required: true },            //activity
},{
  timestamps: false
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Presence_Data_Table', presenceSchema)
```

When I run the code, it could run normally, but after i inputting date "11/06/2020" the result showing  "11/06/2020", why it could be happened? Please help me, I would really appreciate your help

Here the picture before input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCB3s.png)

And, the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z3hm.png)

This is my nodejs code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var Presence = require('../models/presence');
var Auth_mdw = require('../middlewares/auth');

var router = express.Router();
var session_store;

router.get('/', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next) {
    session_store = req.session;

    Presence.find({}, function(err, presence){
        console.log(presence);
        res.render('presences/index', { session_store:session_store, presences: presence });
    });
});

router.get('/add', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next){
    session_store = req.session;

    res.render('presences/add', { session_store:session_store });
});

router.post('/add', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next){
    session_store = req.session;

    req.assert('nama', 'nama diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('tanggal', 'tanggal diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('waktu', 'waktu diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('activity', 'activity diperlukan').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();  
    console.log(errors);

    if (!errors)
    {
        v_nama = req.sanitize( 'nama' ).escape().trim();
        v_tanggal = req.sanitize( 'tanggal' ).escape().trim();
        v_waktu = req.sanitize( 'waktu' ).escape().trim();
        v_activity = req.sanitize( 'activity' ).escape().trim();

        Presence.find({ nama: req.param('nama') }, function (err, presence){
            if (presence.length == 0)
            {
                var presence = new Presence({
                    nama: v_nama,
                    tanggal: v_tanggal,
                    waktu: v_waktu,
                    activity: v_activity,
                });

                presence.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) 
                    {
                        console.log(err);

                        req.flash('msg_error', 'Maaf, sepertinya ada masalah dengan sistem kami...');
                        res.redirect('/presences');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        req.flash('msg_info', 'Presensi berhasil dibuat...');
                        res.redirect('/presences');
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                req.flash('msg_error', 'Maaf, presensi sudah ada...');
                res.render('presences/add', { 
                    session_store:session_store,
                    nama: req.param('nama'),
                    tanggal: req.param('tanggal'),
                    waktu: req.param('waktu'),
                    activity: req.param('activity'),
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {   
        // menampilkan pesan error
        errors_detail = "<p>Maaf, sepertinya ada salah pengisian, tolong dicheck lagi formnya.</p><ul>";

        for (i in errors)
        {
            error = errors[i];
            errors_detail += '<li>'+error.msg+'</li>';
        }

        errors_detail += "</ul>";

        req.flash('msg_error', errors_detail);
        res.render('presences/add', {
            session_store: session_store, 
            nama: req.param('nama'),
            tanggal: req.param('tanggal'),
            waktu: req.param('waktu'),
            activity: req.param('activity'),
        });
    }
});

router.get('/:id/edit', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next){
    session_store = req.session;

    Presence.findOne({ _id:req.params.id}, function (err, presence){
        if (presence)
        {
            console.log(presence);

            res.render('presences/edit', { session_store:session_store, presence:  presence});
        }
        else
        {
            req.flash('msg_error', 'Maaf, presensi tidak ditemukan!');
            res.redirect('/presences');
        }
    });
});

router.put('/:id', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next){
    session_store = req.session;

    req.assert('nama', 'nama diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('tanggal', 'tanggal diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('waktu', 'waktu diperlukan').notEmpty();
    req.assert('activity', 'activity diperlukan').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();  
    console.log(errors);

    if (!errors)
    {
        v_nama = req.sanitize( 'nama' ).escape().trim();
        v_tanggal = req.sanitize( 'tanggal' ).escape().trim();
        v_waktu = req.sanitize( 'waktu' ).escape().trim();
        v_activity = req.sanitize( 'activity' ).escape().trim();

        Presence.findById(req.params.id, function (err, presence){
            presence.nama = v_nama;
            presence.tanggal = v_tanggal;
            presence.waktu = v_waktu;
            presence.activity = v_activity;

            presence.save(function(err) {
                if (err) 
                {
                    console.log(err);

                    req.flash('msg_error', 'Maaf, sepertinya ada masalah dengan sistem kami...');
                    res.redirect('/presences');
                }
                else
                {
                    req.flash('msg_info', 'Edit presensi berhasil...');
                    res.redirect('/presences');
                }
            });

        });
    }
    else
    {   
        // menampilkan pesan error
        errors_detail = "<p>Maaf, sepertinya ada salah pengisian, tolong dicheck lagi formnya.</p><ul>";

        for (i in errors)
        {
            error = errors[i];
            errors_detail += '<li>'+error.msg+'</li>';
        }

        errors_detail += "</ul>";

        req.flash('msg_error', errors_detail);
        res.render('presences/edit', {
            _id: req.params.id,
            session_store: session_store, 
            nama: req.param('nama'),
            tanggal: req.param('tanggal'),
            waktu: req.param('waktu'),
            activity: req.param('activity'),
        });
    }
});

router.delete('/:id', Auth_mdw.check_login, Auth_mdw.is_admin, function(req, res, next){
    Presence.findById(req.params.id, function(err, presence){
        presence.remove(function(err, presence){
            if (err) 
            {
                console.log(err);
                req.flash('msg_error', 'Maaf, sepertinya presensi yang dimaksud sudah tidak ada. Dan sepertinya ada masalah dengan sistem kami ');
            }
            else
            {
                req.flash('msg_info', 'Hapus presensi berhasil!');
            }
            res.redirect('/presences');
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using .escape() thats the reason of convert

Comment: Could you clarify what the effects of that would be? ^^